# How to access a controller or a component from one directory to another in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection, microservices

Tried to access a controller from a parent directory. I have used this method to call it from a child directory.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-core</artifactId>
</dependency
```

Here is the error for the above usage

```
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/sample/src/main/java/com/sample/controllers/abcController.java

package com.sample.controller does not exist
```

Any help is appreciated to help me get access from a parent or a different directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to show to spring that contains other classes to scan beyond your current project

I think you are looking for `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.sample"})` that tells to spring see your third-party packages

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"br.com.scan-others-entities-in-other-projects"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"br.com.my-curent-project", "br.com.scan-other-configs-and-controllers"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"br.com.com-other-repositories"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```